# POST with Nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, post, insomnia

Unfortunately I get an empty `body: {}` in the request object, when I `POST` something to my api via `Insomnia` (configuration Form `Form URL Encoded` Header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

Here is my express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/', function(req, res) {

    test = req.body.test;
    console.log(req);
    console.log(test);
    res.send("Hallo");
});

const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

What am I doing wrong? And also what would I have to change in my code if I'd configure Insomnia to Form as `JSON`, Header `Content-Type: application/json` ?

Answer (score 1):

For accessing request body use `body-parser middleware` and for sending the response in JSON format use `res.json()`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/api/', function(req, res) {
    test = req.body.test;
    console.log(req);
    console.log(test);
    res.json({"message":"Hallo"}); //update here
});

const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Answer (score 1):

available in Express v4.16.0 onwards:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: But how to parse `Content-Type: application/json`? This one still doesn't work.

Comment: Just do not include the line `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`